# SAX Rss Parsing ignore space on setLink

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sax

I have made a RSS reader and could use some help on small problem.  When the rss XML is set up like this:

```
<link>http://www.grants.gov/search/search.do?mode=VIEW&amp;oppId=98616</link>
```

my reader can pull the link fine.

But some feed I am trying to read are set up like:

```
<link>
http://www.ornl.gov/info/ornlreview/v44_1_11/article06.shtml
</link>
```

which causes my reader to miss the link.

I have narrowed the problem down to:

```
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String strCharacters = new String(ch,start,length);
    if (itemFound==true){
    // "item" tag found, it's item's parameter
        switch(currentState){
        case state_title:
            item.setTitle(strCharacters);
            break;
        case state_description:
            item.setDescription(strCharacters);
            break;
        case state_link:
            item.setLink(strCharacters);
            break;
        case state_pubdate:
            item.setPubdate(strCharacters);
            break;  
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

The strCharacters pulls the string in the current row, but with the RSS with a space it just pulls whitespace.  Any ideas on how to get it to skip the white space and pull the link on the next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parser looks weird, try doing this instead:

```
  private StringBuilder builder;   

  @Override
  public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    super.startDocument();
    builder = new StringBuilder();
  }

  @Override
  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
    builder.append(ch, start, length);
  }

  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name) throws SAXException {
    if (currentState == state_link) {
      item.setLink(builder.toString().trim());
    }
    builder.setLength(0);
  }
```

That way you wait until the content is completely consumed, instead of just reading one line of text.

Comment: builder.append(ch, start, length); causes the application to crash

Comment: **thumbs up** much cleaner parsing now..and solved my problem  Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Yes, you really shouldn't be saving any data in characters, only on startTag (to get attributes) and endtag (to save content).

Answer (score 1):

1. Create documentBuilderFactory

   DocumentBuilderFactory factory= 
   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

   1. Create DocumentBuilder

   DocumentBuilder builder=factory. newDocumentBuilder();

   1. get input stream
      ClassLoader cls=DomReader.class.getClassLoader();
      InputStream is=cls.getResourceAsStream("xml file");

      1. parse xml file and get Document object by calling parse method
         on DocumentBuilder object.
         Document document=builder.parse(is);
      2. Traverse dom tree using document object.
         SAX: 
         Simple xml parsing.
         It parses node by node
         Traversing is from top to bottom
         Low memory usage
         Back navigation is not possible with sax.

   //implementing required handlers 
     public class SaxParse extends DefaultHandler{
     }
     //new instance of saxParserFactory
     SAXParserFactory factory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    //NEW INSTANCE OF SAX PARSER
     SAXParser saxparser=factory.newSAXParser();
     //Parsing xml document
    SAXParser.parse(new File(file to be parsed), new SAXXMLParserImpl());